# How to change image when a button is clicked in html

Tags: html

I am learning html and I want to know how I can change an image when a button is clicked. This is what I have so far code below:-

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'">change image</button>

<img id="myImage" src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="800" height="600" longdesc="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
```

I want to be able to change the image when the button is clicked.
So if the image is google then when the button is clicked I want ubuntu to appear and if the image is ubuntu then when the button is clicked I want firefox. I have done it using multiple buttons but I don't know how to use one button to change the image.

If someone could help me that would be great.

Comment: Your code is working, it's just you're replacing the image with the same image again, can you see how it's changing the image src?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using Javascript to switch the image. The counter runs through 1-3 and displays an image accordingly. See the comments for a description of each part. If you desired to expand this to many more images, you could create an array of images and then increment through the array, displaying each one, until the array length is reached, at which point you could begin from the beginning of the array again.

```js
var x = 1; //initializes counter
function switchImg() {
  if (x == 1) { //if the counter is at 1
    document.getElementById("imgToSwitch").src = "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR7pz7PYv3YJ1R391uzau_CS-kXxgpWG8zrDtam-LsUK50KEAM4_wIgKg";
    x++; //increments the counter to 2
  } else if (x == 2) { //if this is the 2nd click
    document.getElementById("imgToSwitch").src = "https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/styleguide/identity/firefox/guidelines-logo.7ea045a4e288.png";
    x++; //increments counter to 3
  } else if (x == 3) { //if the counter is 3
    document.getElementById("imgToSwitch").src = "https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo-1200x630.jpg";
    x = 1; //resets counter to 1
  }
}
```

```css
/*not needed. Just used to make everything pretty. */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<!--calls the function when it is clicked -->
<button type="button" onclick="switchImg()">Click Me!</button>
<!--image with id of "imgToSwitch." This is the content that is targeted -->
<img src="https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo-1200x630.jpg" id="imgToSwitch">
```

Comment: Sorry the stretched ubuntu logo was making me twitch 